# Inserting NameValueCollection into a datatable which is giving me errors such as This row already belongs to this table

Tags: c#, asp.net

New to asp.net and C# any help would be great Thank you.

My code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string x = "item_name1=number1&item_number1=product1";
        NameValueCollection key = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(x);
        DataTable Theproducts = new DataTable();

        Theproducts.Columns.Add("ProductID");
        Theproducts.Columns.Add("ProductName");
        DataRow row = Theproducts.NewRow();        
        int index = 1;
        foreach(string keys in key.AllKeys)
        {
            if (keys == ("item_number" + index.ToString()))
            {
                row["ProductID"] = key[keys];
            }
            if (keys == ("item_name" + index.ToString()))
            {
                row["ProductName"] = key[keys];
            }
            Theproducts.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = Theproducts;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }//end of button
```

getting error This row already belongs to this table.

Answer (score 3):

You need to move the `DataRow` declaration inside the foreach loop.

```
foreach(string keys in key.AllKeys)
{
      DataRow row = Theproducts.NewRow(); 
      if (keys == ("item_number" + index.ToString()))
      {
            row["ProductID"] = key[keys];
      }
      if (keys == ("item_name" + index.ToString()))
      {
            row["ProductName"] = key[keys];
      }
      Theproducts.Rows.InsertAt(row,0);
}
```

Currently you are creating the DataRow object **outside of the foreach loop**, and on each iteration you are trying to insert the same object to the datatable. That is why you are getting the error.

Comment: the problem is it will skill the second column for example it would display productid then skip productname and add it to th second row.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the row insert outside your loop

```
    DataRow row = Theproducts.NewRow();
    foreach(string keys in key.AllKeys)
    {
      -------
    }      
    Theproducts.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);
```

in your code, you try to insert the same Row for every key present (two or more times). But your table schema requires a row with only two columns.
So you need to wait the end of the loop ending before trying to insert.

Answer (score 0):

It's like you were adding the same instance (row), to the datatable over and over each time. You were modifying the same row object. Moving the new row creation into the loop will solve that as new row object is created in each iteration

```
    int index = 1;
    foreach(string keys in key.AllKeys)
    {
        DataRow row = Theproducts.NewRow();

        if (keys == ("item_number" + index.ToString()))
        {
            row["ProductID"] = key[keys];
        }
        if (keys == ("item_name" + index.ToString()))
        {
            row["ProductName"] = key[keys];
        }
        Theproducts.Rows.InsertAt(row, 0);
    }
```